# Selecting attachment with FZF in Mutt

Tags: mutt, fzf

I'm trying to create a macros to integrate fzf with mutt for selecting attachments. I have tried:

```
    
macro compose H "<attach-file> c <kill-line> <shell-escape> /usr/bin/fzf <enter>"
```

Unfortunately I couldn't get the output of the command fzf and change directory. Any ideas on how to do it?

(It would be even better if I could select  the file in fzf and automatically attach it without changing folder and select the file and then press enter)

Thank you

Comment: For the ones interested, I created a python script as editor (muttrc: set editor = "python SCRIPT") which: 1) opens the file with VI; 2) after the user closed the file, it checks the text of the email and if it finds some key words ("attached, "attach", etc.) it opens fzf and you select the attachments

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but I use ranger (coupled with fzf) and neomutt-file-picker to do what you want to select files. Look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73946532/14450207